# MQ Client to use with Python that does not require installing

Tags: java, python, ibm-mq, jython, pymqi

I am looking for an MQ Client to use with Python \ Jython.

Looking for a stand-alone program so that I dont have to install anything in the machine I am running as it may have to be run on multiple machines. So I guess Websphere is ruled out. Want something which is stand alone, may be a jar that can be imported through Jython but if something could work using Python compiler and additional library that would be great.

Comment: Do you need to connect with a specific type of MQ server such as IBM MQ or others?

Comment: Yes , IBM MQ. I have installed websphere in my machine but not sure I can import into my pydev project to operate it as stand alone

Comment: You can download the "Java-All" package for v8 or v9 of MQ.  This includes all the jar files required to use the IBM MQ Classes for JMS in a self extracting jar.  You can use these jar files with Python via PyJava or Spring Python.  If this is the info you are looking for I'll post an answer with the links to the Java-All downloads.

Comment: Hi Josh, Yes, that's what I am looking for, I can import the jar in my PyDev project , any pointers to functions they expose would help as well . Thanks in advance

Comment: JoshMC , Can you please share the path to link to Java-all and any implementation method in python if you have?

Comment: google MQC8 for MQ v8.0, MQC9 for MQ v9.0, or MQC91 for MQ v9.1. Once you have clicked the link to access Fixcentral get the file with a name like v9.1's 9.1.0.0-IBM-MQ-Java-All

Comment: also regarding your comment to David Ware that PyMQI is ruled out as it requires Websphere to be installed, this is not true, IBM provides a Redistributable install packages now which is just distributed as a unix tar file or windows zip file that you can extract and distribute with your application.

Comment: thanks, did the extraction of the Websphere package and managed to use it, that works now perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the download of the redistributable client that JoshMc mentions, you might be interested in the fact that the MQ jars are also available through Maven https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2018/01/09/developing-mq-java-applications-maven/

There are also open source ways to talk to MQ with Python. For a simple pub/sub API there is the MQ Light API that talks AMQP to MQ (client can be found here https://github.com/mqlight/python-mqlight).

There's also the PyMQI project (https://pythonhosted.org/pymqi/), this requires an MQ client on the system, so you'd use the same redistributable MQ client package to obtain that.

Comment: Thanks David, python mqlight does not look like is for IBM MQ. PyMQI is ruled out as it requires Websphere to be installed. I will try the com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar

Comment: MQ Light clients work with IBM MQ over AMQP channels. You'll need at least an MQ 8.0.0.4 which is when MQ added support for AMQP channels.

Comment: References to WebSphere in the PyMQI doc are referring to the old name of IBM MQ, which was WebSphere MQ, not WebSphere Application Server.